# Use Intellij and netbeans at the same time in the same workspace

Tags: java, intellij-idea, netbeans, virtualbox

I was provided with a Ubuntu virtual box that has netbeans installed whereas locally I have Intellij. My Java workspace is shared between guest and host, therefore I was wondering if there will be any kind of conflict by running Intellij and Netbeans at the same time in such conditions.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the guest-and-host-OSes condition would play into this but I am pretty sure otherwise that the workspace can be shared by both of them especially when they are not working on the same project. Even if they are, it'd be you who'd be getting confused as files would get updated on both IDEs as the other one makes any changes.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any conflict as long as you have read/write permissions on both the OSs. 
However, to track the changes to code in a better way, use a version control system like [subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/).

Also, `do not copy the resources` to your workspaces. Instead check out the code directly to your workspace.

Answer (score 1):

This don't cause conflicts because each IDE adds a set of configuration files per project, for example: netbeans generates the `nbproject` folder, where is the project configuration for that IDE, while intellij generates a `projectName.iml` file and the `.idea` folder where is the configuration for the project.

If you use a version control tool as *git, svn, mercurial,* is recommended that you synchronize your project in each environment *(guest and host)* with your repository and do not share the workspace between them.

Comment: I am using git, but I'm only interested in synchronising on the host side. It should not be a problem, correct?

Comment: If you develop in both environments (guest and host) then you should synchronize both, so you will have the latest version in those environments,  otherwise it is not necessary